# When uname reports aarch64 instead of arm64v8. Willl docker-ce still pull arm64v8 images

Tags: docker, arm

docker-ce now supports multiple architecture base images but looks for the tag arm64v8 instead of aarch64 (which is labelled as deprecated).

Unfortunately my new ubuntu 18.04 host os uname reports aarch64.
`Linux nas 4.4.154-1122-rockchip-ayufan-g7859b9b904a9 #1 SMP Mon Oct 1 07:32:42 UTC 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

So

1. Can one manually add/change the architecture tag in a already operational host?
   or
2. Will docker-ce pull the arm64v8 image even if the host os reports aarch64?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that's ok. I did not test with Ubuntu 18.04 but with latest Debian everything is working fine on my Pine64 :

```
root@pine64:~# uname -a
Linux pine64 3.10.107-pine64 #7 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 25 08:00:55 CET 2018 aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@pine64:~# docker info | grep arch
Architecture: aarch64
```

I have downloaded many arm64v8 images without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think docker uses uname for anything. I think the default architecture is a property of the install package.  That is the package you get when you install with apt-get.

This takes care of any mismatch in naming convention between Ubuntu and docker.

As it is docker's [own naming is a bit inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70748609/how-do-platform-architectures-map-to-docker-manifest-architectures).

If you want to change the default... If you add the environment variable DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM to your profile, you can change the default platform.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/